# How to programmatically create dummy email thread?

Tags: python, linux, email, command-line-interface, dummy-data

For comparing some software I need a thread of mails, i.e. some mails with replies and replies to the replies... Content does not matter, but attachment and richt-text would be nice.

I wonder how to create such a dummy mail thread programmatically (preferably using Linux commandline tools or Python).

How would I create those dummy mails?

Comment: do you need to send the emails or just create them?

Comment: @Noelkd Just create them.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html ?

Comment: Yeah, that would probably be the right library. Maybe someone already wrote a script using it for such a task...

Comment: hopefully that's the case

Comment: if content doesn't matter wouldn't it be simpler to just download some mailing list archives?